# ASP.NET membership - User exists but can't log in

Tags: asp.net-membership

Having my website open in Visual Studio I go to Website|ASP.NET configuration. The I click the Security tab. From there I create a new user. I assign a role to it. Then when I try to log in to my website using it I get Login failure. I deleted and recreated the user 10 times. But the problem persists. I checked the Membeship table, the userid exists in the table. It's approved and is not locked out. What else do I have to check? I can log in using previously created users.

Comment: Did you create the project on a different computer?